# How do I stop the others validations to validate when the attribute is not :present in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, dry, dsl, skip

What I'm curretly doing is the following:

```
validates :new_pass,
          :presence => {:if => :new_record?},
          :confirmation => {:if => :password_not_blank?},
          :length => {:within => 6...64, :if => :password_not_blank?}

def password_not_blank?
  !new_pass.blank?
end
```

But that is not DRY, I bet there is a way to skip the validations if the attribute is not present.

Also, there isn't any DSL method for validating? I think it would be cleaner than implementing logic inside hashes...

-- Edit, thanks ^^ --

This is what I got now:

```
validates :new_pass,
          :allow_blank => {:on => :update},
          :presence => {:on => :create},
          :confirmation => true,
          :length => {:within => 6...64}
```

And just for the record and so no one worries (?), this is a virtual attribute, the actual password is encrypted with a before_save, checking that :new_pass is not blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`:allow_nil` flag for `validates`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Validations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-validates) might be of interest. Something like this should work:

```
validates :new_pass,
          :allow_nil => true,
          :presence => {:if => :new_record?},
          :confirmation => {:if => :password_not_blank?},
          :length => {:within => 6...64, :if => :password_not_blank?}
```

Comment: Thanks! I think that what I needed was :allow_blank, since the :new_pass may be set to an empty string. Also, I wouldn't need the :if

Comment: @Zequez: I went with `:allow_nil` due to the presence of `:X_not_blank?` options, but you're sorted out so we're all good.

Answer (score 0):

```
validates :new_pass,:presence => true ,:if => :new_record?
validates :confirmation ,:length =>:within => 6...64, :if => :password_not_blank?
```